# How can I remove features/columns of a data frame if at least 20% of their entries take a specific value, using pandas/numpy?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am using pandas and numpy.

I want to remove every column in my 9000 x 13 training data frame where at least 20% of the entries take the value -200. In this case, -200 is like a missing value or NaN, so I am removing variables that aren't useful. I have a sample of the data below. Any help would be appreciated.
This is some kind of attempt:
`train_mod = train.loc[:, train.isnull().mean() <.2]`

```
A        B        C            D      E                 F          \
5723     0.5       846.25      -200    2.619270         627.50     79.0   
4014     1.5      1016.25      -200    6.810175         848.50     99.0   
4074     2.0      -200.00      -200    -200.000        -200.00    114.0   
4577     1.6       950.50      -200    8.649763         925.50    351.0   
6691     4.7      1469.75      -200   25.820425        1449.75    677.0   
2889     0.5       902.50      -200    2.676091         631.25   -200.0   
4387     2.0      1095.75      -200   12.972673        1082.75    310.0   
4289     1.0       885.50      -200    2.695146         632.50   -200.0   
2887     2.3      1355.00      -200   16.611225        1198.25    129.0   
5694     1.1       936.25      -200    6.821513         849.00    127.0
```

Comment: why you want to do that. Do you want to reduce the memory size ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a column in pandas dataframe based on a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614804/how-to-delete-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-condition)

Answer (score 0):

```
val = -200
rows_20 = df.shape[0] // 5

train_mod = train[[c for c in train.columns if (train[c] == val).sum() <= rows_20]]
```

Explanation:

`train[c] == val` 
returns a Series of booleans (True/False). Calling .sum() on this counts the number of "True" values. This is then checked against `row_20`, which is 20% of the number of rows in the DataFrame.

The list comprehension returns only columns that match the `if` condition.

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: @EduardoBaitello fair enough, although that link doesn't mention anything about code only answers

Answer (score 0):

You may try creating a new `"tagging_column"` using `numpy.where()`. Then use it to create a counting column in `groupby` then aggregate on count. Then finally compute for the ratio. If the ratio is `>=20%` Drop all tagged at `minus 200 or lower value`.

Consider:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'val':[100,200,-250,2000,20312039,12485,-300,-350,-60494]})
>>> df
   id       val
0   1       100
1   2       200
2   3      -250
3   4      2000
4   5  20312039
5   6     12485
6   7      -300
7   8      -350
8   9    -60494

>>> df['Check Negative 200'] = np.where(df['val'] <=-200, ['Negative 200 or lower'], ['Greater than -200'])
>>> df
   id       val     Check Negative 200  Count
0   1       100      Greater than -200      5
1   2       200      Greater than -200      5
2   3      -250  Negative 200 or lower      4
3   4      2000      Greater than -200      5
4   5  20312039      Greater than -200      5
5   6     12485      Greater than -200      5
6   7      -300  Negative 200 or lower      4
7   8      -350  Negative 200 or lower      4
8   9    -60494  Negative 200 or lower      4

>>> df['Count'] = df.groupby('Check Negative 200')['Check Negative 200'].transform('count')
>>> df
   id       val     Check Negative 200  Count
0   1       100      Greater than -200      5
1   2       200      Greater than -200      5
2   3      -250  Negative 200 or lower      4
3   4      2000      Greater than -200      5
4   5  20312039      Greater than -200      5
5   6     12485      Greater than -200      5
6   7      -300  Negative 200 or lower      4
7   8      -350  Negative 200 or lower      4
8   9    -60494  Negative 200 or lower      4

>>> dd = dict(df['Check Negative 200'].value_counts())
>>> dd
{'Greater than -200': 5, 'Negative 200 or lower': 4}

if dd['Negative 200 or lower']/len(df) > .2:
    df = df[df['Check Negative 200'].isin(['Greater than -200'])]
else:
    pass

>>> df
   id       val Check Negative 200  Count
0   1       100  Greater than -200      5
1   2       200  Greater than -200      5
3   4      2000  Greater than -200      5
4   5  20312039  Greater than -200      5
5   6     12485  Greater than -200      5
```

You can also drop the added columns so your columns would remain the same as the input.

```
>>> del df['Check Negative 200']
>>> del df['Count']
>>> df.reset_index(inplace = True, drop = True)
>>> df
   id       val
0   1       100
1   2       200
2   4      2000
3   5  20312039
4   6     12485
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat convoluted one-liner that should do the trick:

```
df_mod = df[df.columns[(df == -200).sum()/df.shape[0] < 0.2]]
```

Essentially, going from the inside out, we're seeing how many values in each column are invalid (`df == -200`). The sum over that bracket sums over boolean values, so it counts the `True` entries. We divide this by the number of rows, and where this value is less than 20%, the columns are kept. We then take the DataFrame where the columns fulfill this condition, and are left with the columns where less than 20% of entries are invalid.

Hope this helps!