# Drop Columns in Data based on Condition

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a DataFrame with 1 Row and 33 Columns.
I want to delete the columns where it finds a number between 0 and 30 and also nan values.

Is there any efficient way to do that?

Comment: Please search before posting. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614804/how-to-delete-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-condition

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to try doing it:

```
filtered = df.loc[:, ~((df.isnull()) | (df.sum(axis=0)<=30) & (df.sum(axis=0)>=0)).iloc[0]]
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. It has been flagged as low quality and could be deleted if not improved.