# dropping columns contains a particular value (not string)

Tags: python, pandas

I am just trying to select the columns of my dat frame that only contains number greater than zero(I am dropping them off). But I am having some hard time.Here is what I am doing doing:
**I am using the boston dataset from sklearn by the way**.

```
def positivecol(data):
    for col in data.columns:
       if data[col].eq(0):
          data.drop(col,1, inplace=True)
    return data
```

Could someone give me a good explanation as well, please

Comment: Please provide a sample of your input and output so we can better understand what you're trying to do

Comment: See the top answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Comment: @G.Anderson thanks. I am using the boston data from sklearn

Comment: @Joe, I used it. However it only gives me dataset full of booleans

Comment: Explicit loops should be a **last resort** when working with Pandas. Can you share an example of your data?

Comment: @Shyryu Those are probably meant to be used for boolean indexing. Have you read the Pandas docs?

Comment: This is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31614804/11301900.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the method `any`

```
def positivecol(data):
    for col in data.columns:
        if (data[col]<0).any():
            data.drop(col,1, inplace=True)
    return data
```

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT:** This is a duplicate of [How to delete a column in pandas dataframe based on a condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31614804/11301900)

Instead of a loop, we can use an idiomatic Pandas solution:

```py
df.loc[:, df.ge(0).all()]
```