# How do I drop columns in a pandas dataframe based on the count of NaN

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan, drop

Is there an easy way to drop columns that are predominately NaN?

I have a dataframe with 129 columns, I would like to drop all columns with 50% or greater NaN values.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614804/how-to-delete-a-column-in-pandas-dataframe-based-on-a-condition

Answer (score 1):

You could do it as follows:

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

```
# calculate the ratio of nans
nan_ratio= df.isna().mean(axis='index')
# get the columns above a threshold of nans
# here 50% or more NaNs
cols_to_drop= nan_ratio.index[nan_ratio>=0.5].to_list()
# remove the columns from the dataframe
df.drop(columns=cols_to_drop, inplace=True)
df
```

Testdata:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        c1=np.random.randint(1,100, size=100), 
        c2=np.random.randint(1,30, size=100), 
        c3=np.random.randint(1,15, size=100),
        c4=np.random.randint(1,16, size=100)
    ), 
    dtype='float32'
)
df= df.where(df > 10, np.nan)
```

For the test data, the code above would usually delete columns `c3` and `c4` (depending on the random numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I've found another way as well:

```
threshold = 0.25
df = df[df.columns[df.isnull().mean() < threshold]]
```